# How do I register a Type in Autofac with a parameter and resolve it with parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Can I register a type with a constructor parameter, and pass a parameter when I resolve it? Essentially combining the parameters?

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
    .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "session"
    , (p, c) => { 
        return FindTheSession();
    }
);

//somewhere else in the code
((AutofacDependencyResolver)DependencyResolver.Current).RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve(typeof(Foo), new NamedParameter("instance", this));

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(object session, object instance) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the registrations like this:

```cs
builder
    .Register((c, p) => new Foo(
        c.ResolveKeyed<object>("session"),
        p.Named<object>("instance")));

builder
    .Register(c => FindTheSession())
    .Keyed<object>("session");
```

Of course, if `session` is a unique type and not just `object`, then you could just register and resolve it as the type and not have to use the `Keyed` syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately the instance parameter cannot be accessed at this point.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It's not being accessed at this point. You're in a delegate that will be ran later.

Comment: Hey, I apologize for my ignorance. I took the time today to implement and understand your solution and it works great. I'm still fairly new to Autofac.